# UITextView's Text Overlaps When Scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UILabel and UITextView added into a UIViewController's view like in the screenshot below.

[image]

When I typed some words and uitextview starts scrolling, it overlaps the title of the label like below.

[image]

I tried to set textView's **textContainerInset** but it didn't work as I expected. It started the text 10pt below the normal position but still overlapped when it was scrolled.

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: How are you positioning the UILabel and UITextView? Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Yeah, seems like you're positioning the UIlabel and UITextView to have the same y coordinate. Might be easier if you show us your code to setup the interface elements. Ideally, you should ensure UITextView's frame y coordinate is UILabel's frame y coordinate + UILabel's frame size height.

Comment: Hide it on scroll or use layout manager and make it a part of text view, but this is tricky.

Comment: Not that tricky. Like @Zhang said, just move your UITextView down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have place TextView upon UILabel. Move the UILabel up or TextView down, hope that will solve the problem.

```
 CGRect frame = theLabel.frame;
 frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 20;
 theLabel.frame= frame;
```

This will move the label 20px up.

Hope this helps... :)